# SQL database delivering empty results when it should not

Tags: mysql, sql

We tried the following query on our mysql server running Ubuntu 16.07:

```
select id, game_id, competition_id 

from groups
where game_id IS NULL
and competition_id = 1166
```

We knew there were loads of entries having NULL as game_id and 1166 as competition_id, yet the query returned no results.

So after some trying around we found the following works:

```
select id, game_id, competition_id
    from groups
    where game_id IS NULL
    and competition_id > 1165
    and competition_id < 1167
```

but this doesn't:

```
select id, game_id, competition_id 
    from groups
    where game_id IS NULL
    and competition_id > 1165
    and competition_id < 1167
    and bcompetition_id = 1166
```

We tried it on our dev database and it worked just fine, so we concluded we would restart the mysql server. After doing so all of the above queries worked just fine.

What was this? How can we avoid this in the future? How can we make sure there are no other errors like this?

Comment: What is the data type of `competition_id` field?

Comment: Have you tried to copy the entire table from PROD to DEV?

Comment: Not before restarting our server, sadly. And it works now in production as well.